# lambda not accepting keyword arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After upgrading my application from Ruby 2.7.5 to 3.2.2 I've run into this issue. The Rails version is 6.0.6.1.

I have a lambda, used in a scope, which has both a positional argument and a keyword argument. Since upgrading, the keyword argument is not accepted and an ArgumentError is thrown saying there's a wrong number of arguments.

A breaking changed was introduced in Ruby 3.0 related to positional and keyword arguments, see [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/), but I don't think this explains the issue.

Here's an example:

```ruby
class TestClass
  scope :test_scope, lambda do |arg1, arg2:|
    puts arg1
    puts arg2
  end
end
```

When calling the scope, these are the errors:

```ruby
> TestClass.test_scope
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1; required keyword: arg2) (ArgumentError)

> TestClass.test_scope('abc')
missing keyword: :arg2 (ArgumentError)

> TestClass.test_scope('abc', arg2: 'def')
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: arg2) (ArgumentError)
```

I've tried a few variations, but nothing seems to work. If I create a regular method in the class with the same signature, I don't have this error.

What is going wrong here?

**Update**

Here's a full stack trace based on the example provided in the comments.

Example:

```
ExampleClass.test_scope('abc', arg2: 'def')
```

Stacktrace:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: arg2)
  /app/app/models/example_class.rb:2:in `block in <class:ExampleClass>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:411:in `instance_exec'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:411:in `block in _exec_scope'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:804:in `_scoping'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:411:in `_exec_scope'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.3/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:176:in `block in scope'
  /app/config/initializers/test_init.rb:13:in `<main>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
  /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/configuration.rb:348:in `load_rackup'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/configuration.rb:270:in `app'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/runner.rb:150:in `load_and_bind'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/single.rb:44:in `run'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:193:in `run'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/cli.rb:81:in `run'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `load'
  /bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma:25:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: What Rails version? Most likely this does have to do with "Ruby 3.0 related to positional and keyword arguments" in conjunction with incompatibility in argument forwarding in the rails version you are using. You will likely need to update rails to 6.1+ at a minimum.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Rails 6.0 for the moment. Do you have a reference to this argument forwarding in Rails?

Comment: Rails 6.0.X forwards arguments to a scope proc [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d2391f30f9211714f26bbf3b99d8596f8702b5bd/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L175) as `_exec_scope(*args, &body)` and executed as `instance_exec(*args, &block)` where as 6.1 added [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L409) `RUBY_VERSION < "2.7" ? "*args, &block" : "..."` and rails 7 dropped the < 2.7 support all together.

Comment: Your issue as can be ascertained from this line `RUBY_VERSION < "2.7" ? "*args, &block" : "..."` is that your Ruby version (3.2.2) does not support this syntax `_exec_scope(*args, &body)` for forwarding kwargs but that is still what rails 6.0.X is using. Upgrading to 6.1 will solve this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, after upgrading to 6.1.7.3, it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I still get the same error. Before, my Ruby version was 2.7.5, so I guess that version check didn't apply anyway.

Comment: The reason the "version check didn't apply" was 1) there was no version check in 6.0; 2) 2.7 was cross compatible with both syntaxes (where 3.0+ is not). As for your actual issue I cannot recreate this in rails 6.1.0 with ruby 3.0.3 (version in repl.it rails). [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/VapidHandyAmoebas#config/initializers/test_class_test_scope.rb); however i did have to change the implementation of the lambda to `->(arg1,arg2:){}` because the usage in the post raises an `ArgumentError` due to the precedence of `do...end` blocks.

Comment: Okay, but I'm upgrading to Ruby 3.2, so this 3.0 version does not apply here. I've just tried with the other lambda syntax, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I suspect some other gem is messing with this. When I execute your example in my project, I get this error: 

```#########################
#
# Executing: ExampleClass.test_scope('abc', arg2: 'def')
#
#########################

Result:

ruby version: 3.2.2
rails version: 6.1.7.3

! Unable to load application: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: arg2)
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/bundle/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: arg2)```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: @engineersmnky here you go.

Comment: I confirmed locally that your example works on Ruby 3.0.3 and 3.1.4. It does not work on 3.2.2.

Comment: @engineersmnky I posted an answer below with what's going on here if you're curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same issue today while working on upgrading a Rails 6.1 app to use Ruby 3.2.

The problem is that the Ruby 3.2 compatibility fixes for Rails are currently on the `6-1-stable` branch, but the most recent 6.1 release as of this writing, 6.1.7.3, does not have that commit included.

Unless a new 6.1 release is shipped with that commit, it would appear the only way to get Rails 6.1 working with Ruby 3.2 is by pointing directly to the `6.1-stable` branch on GitHub (I have not tried this, however).

See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46895 for details.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. On Github someone mentions that they won't release Rails 6.1.8, so the only way is to point to `6.1.-stable`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be easier to change scopes to `positional` arguments rather than updating rails version

```
# from
scope :by_sorted_search, ->(search_term: nil, title_order: nil) { ... }

# to
scope :by_sorted_search, ->(search_term = nil, title_order = nil) { ... }
```