# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)) - Ruby 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am migrating from Ruby 2.7.2 to ruby 3.2.2 and now, when I call the "update" method, I receive the following error:
`ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))`

Here is the code:

```
def update
   @course = Course.find params[:id]
   @course.update(course_params)
end

private 

def course_params
   params.require(:course).permit(:name, :start_date, :duration)
end
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Ruby: 3.2.2
Rails: 6.0

Stack trace:
[image]

Comment: Please try this, `@course.update(course_params, {})` are you sure not another method exist to update the course

Comment: Nothing.. if try `@course.update(course_params, {})` I receive `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: then, I think this would be related to upgrade Rails, or related packages, it maybe need to do `bundle update`

Comment: Remove any validations within the model, to make sure that is `update` throw that error

Comment: Cant see anything obviously wrong. Can you add the full backtrace?

Comment: You could try `**course_params` in the `update` but I suspect this is something deeper in the stack, so a more complete trace will help. Ruby 3.2 uses the new *kwargs* handling which can conflict with Rails < 7. One thing to try is updating to the latest 6.0 version (6.0.6.1 currently) to see if Ruby 3 compatibility has been improved.

Comment: Please post `course.rb` and the output of `params` and `course_params`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: Hi guys, I have attached the stacktrace

Comment: Your issue is rails 6.0 and ruby 3.2 are not compatible. See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173080/lambda-not-accepting-keyword-arguments). Options include: 1) update to 6.1-stable (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46895 ) or 7.0 to use that ruby version; 2) downgrade ruby to <3.2 and upgrade to rails 6.1; 3) downgrade to ruby 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [article](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) that lists Ruby and Rails Compatibility (updated March 13, 2023).

Perhaps the upgrade path of Rails 6 to 6.1 might be the best course.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-6-0-to-rails-6-1